# Eclipse with ABAP extension - SAP Gui Menu not closable

Tags: abap, abap-adt

Just want to try out the ABAP Tools for Eclipse and start with developing cds-views through Eclipse. The main problem is that after opening the SAP-GUI menu as in the screenshot, the menu is not closable anymore.

Problem occurs with version 2019-03 and 2019-06 with up-to-date ABAP-Tools.

[image: red rectangle shows the menu which is not closable]

Clicking the menu again doesn't do anything sadly. The menu keeps open and I can't even press anything more in Eclipse and have to restart it fully.

Comment: If you are doing CDS dev, you don't need the SAP GUI. : )

Comment: Yeah, that's mostly correct ;) But if I am logged into the system and want to watch after another table or something which has nothing to do with CDS it would be great if the UI would work fine.

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug even on previous releases.

You may close the context menu manually by clicking the menu again or the left side of the title bar.

PS: that's weird but I observe that I cannot reproduce what you describe anymore on my current version! (Eclipse 2019-06, ADT 2019-06, SAP GUI 7.50, backend 7.52 SP00 and SP01). Note: ADT 2019-06 has been released approximately on July, 15th.

Comment: Clicking the menu again doesn't do anything sadly. The menu keeps open and I can't even press anything more in Eclipse and have to restart it fully.